# Add custom method in mapstruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

```
@Override
    @Mappings(
        {
            @Mapping(target = "temperature", source = "pac.temperature"),
            @Mapping(target = "containerId", ignore=true),

        }
    )
    TargetABC toDto(Source source);


@AfterMapping
default void inRange(Source source, @MappingTarget TargerABC target) {

    
        var temperature = source.getPac.getTemperature();
        var range = source.getRange();
        target.setContainerId(
            range.calculate(temperature)
        );
    
}
```

at the moment I have a solution using `@AfterMapping`, but I want to get rid of this approach in favor of `qualifiedByName` and do the mapping in the field itself by adding a method with the `@Named` annotation, is it possible that such a method will take two values? Maybe there is another better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define custom method which will accept `Source`as parameter and will make required computations. Call this method from `@Mapping` using `expression= "java(<method_name>)"`.

```
@Mapping(target = "containerId",expression = "java(calculateContainerId(source))")
TargetABC toDto(Source source);

default String calculateContainerId(Source source) {
        var temperature = source.getPac.getTemperature();
        var range = source.getRange();
       
        return range.calculate(temperature); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is defining a default method for mapping `source` to `containerId`, which would MapStruct recognize and use if you define `source` as the source used for mapping, as shown below:

```java
@Mapping(target = "temperature", source = "pac.temperature")
@Mapping(target = "containerId", source = "source")
TargerABC toDto(Source source);

default Integer calculateContainerIdFromSource(Source source) {
  var temperature = source.getPac().getTemperature();
  var range = source.getRange();
  return range.calculate(temperature);
}
```